# Onclick document element disabled permanently?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm trying to manipulate a checkbox. If you select this check box the rest of the checkboxes are disabled. What I have so far works. Except when you uncheck it. The checkboxes are still disabled. I was searching for maybe a way to uncheck disabled false perhaps.

```
 <input name="Package" type="checkbox" id="Package" on   onClick="document.getElementById('Gala').checked = this.checked; document.getElementById('Gala').disabled=true; " value="1" maxlength="1" <?=($fullPackageYes)?> />
```

Comment: Try using `onchange` instead of `onclick`

Comment: what about `document.getElementById('Gala').checked = document.getElementById('Gala').disabled = this.checked;`

Answer (score 2):

```
 <input name="Package" onclick="disable_checkboxes(this)" type="checkbox" id="Package" value="1" maxlength="1" <?=($fullPackageYes)?> />

<script>
function disable_checkboxes(ele){

    if(ele.checked == 'checked'){
        document.getElementById('Gala').checked = 'checked'; 
        document.getElementById('Gala').disabled='disabled';
    }else {
        document.getElementById('Gala').checked = ''; 
        document.getElementById('Gala').disabled='';   
    }
 }
 </script>
```

Apparently your question was solved by @david, however I would strongly advise you to switch it to something more like the above code, inline javascript is not very good practice at all.

Comment: This is indeed the cleaner way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Live demo: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3AaPP/2/)

```
<input id="package" name="Package" type="checkbox" id="Package" value="1" maxlength="1" <?=($fullPackageYes)?> checked />

<input type="checkbox" id="Gala" value="1" maxlength="1"/> Gala

<script>
var Gala = document.getElementById('Gala');

document.getElementById('package').onclick=function(){
    Gala.disabled = this.checked ? "" : "disabled";
    Gala.checked = this.checked ? Gala.checked : "";
}
</script>
```

Comment: if you check one then check the other, the other one appears disabled but checked in your demo